# Android - Read attachment from email client app with my app

Tags: android, email-attachments

I'd like to open an attachment (e.g InputStream) from android E-mail app with my app.
I'm able to associate my app to open a specific file from E-mail, but when i get uri like

`content://com.samsung.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/176/RAW`

i'm not able to open the stream and SecurityException is thrown:
`Permission Denial: opening provider
 com.samsung.android.email.provider.provider.attachment.AttachmentProvider 
 from ProcessRecord{83b03a2 11090:com.test.att/u0a416}
 (pid=11090, uid=10416) requires com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER or com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER`.
I tried to add this permission in manifest file and grant read permission before using ContentProvider in code but another exception is thrown:

`Uid xxx does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://......`

Example:
`Uri uri = mInitApp.geIntent().getData();
mCtx.grantUriPermission(mCtx.getPackageName(), uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
InputStream in = mCtx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`

The strange thing is if i try many times to open the attachment with my app, granting permission, sometimes i'm able to read attachment (uri remain the same).
For a practical usage i don't want to download manually attachment and select it from Download folder.
Am i missing something?
Thanks

Comment: You cannot grant yourself a permission. Only the content provider can do so. The consumer can only get a permission and take it.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to open that inputstream?

Comment: In my custom class, on main activity app, on main thread. My app starts when i click on attachment in E-mail. The file a custom kml file, i need to read some row.
Is there another way to access the attachment without manually saving it?

Comment: `tried to add this permission in manifest file`. How exactly?

Comment: Have you inspected `intent.getFlags()` ? Which ones did you get?

Comment: As usually `<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER"/>` I take a look to email manifest to get some information.

Comment: I get `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. My Activity is `singleTask`

Comment: That flag you get from Android. That is not enough. You should get at least some read permission flag too from the email app. Which email app you use? Try with other email apps. Which Android version? Try other Android versions too.

Comment: When sometimes it works i have the same flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. I tried with gmail too and i have the same problem when i try to grant permission, uri change of course. I tried with android 6.0 and 5.1 with different building and target

Comment: `the same problem when i try to grant permission`. As said before: you cannot grant a permission to yourself.

Comment: Hello, any idea of how to solve this error? Im getting the same with gmail